# Why is monomial list failing here?

Tags: polynomials

I've tried to use `MonomialList` here but it seems to be failing:

```
x = X - g/a;
y = Y - f/b;

A = Collect[Expand[a x^2 + 2 h x y + b y^2 + 2 g x + 2 f y + c], {X, Y, X Y}] // TraditionalForm      
B = Collect[Expand[a x^2 + b y^2 + 2 g x + 2 f y + c], {X, Y}] // TraditionalForm
MonomialList[A, {X, Y}]
```

When I try to use it, it gives me:

[image]

I have no idea about why this is happening. I guess It's because of the constant terms, but I don't know what I should use to group the constants.

Comment: On Mathematica 10.3.0.0 on Mac OS X I get `{a X^2, b Y^2, c - f^2/b - g^2/a}`. Also, please post your code so others don't have to write it by hand.

Comment: @Graumagier Corrected, sorry. I'm using Mathematica 10.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Get rid of the `TraditionalForm`, and it should work. `TraditionalForm` is a wrapper for an expression that makes it display nicely, but this actually *changes the expression* and should only be used if the only thing you are doing is displaying the expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = X - g/a;
y = Y - f/b;
```

Use parentheses to keep the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) wrapper from being included in the definitions of `A` and `B`

```
(A = Collect[
    Expand[a x^2 + 2 h x y + b y^2 + 2 g x + 2 f y + c], {X, Y, 
     X Y}]) // TraditionalForm

(B = Collect[
    Expand[a x^2 + b y^2 + 2 g x + 2 f y + c], {X, Y}]) // TraditionalForm

MonomialList[A, {X, Y}]

(*  {a X^2, 2 h X Y, -((2 f h X)/b), b Y^2, -((2 g h Y)/a), 
 c - f^2/b - g^2/a + (2 f g h)/(a b)}  *)
```

Comment: I swear I have tried to take the TraditionalForm's and it still didn't work. Now I tried and it worked.